Why is task scheduler not executing my task even though it says its running?
Task scheduler is not running the bat file that it suppose to run. it states that it is running with code (0x41301). how can i fix this?
CONTEXT
I have a python file that modifies a json file and starts the application related to that json file (in my case its GHelper). To run that python file, I wrote a script in CMD to first close GHelper then run the python file. Thus, the full flow is Close GHelper(done with taskkill in CMD) then modify the json file and reopen GHelper(done by python). Here is the Command prompt script
@echo off
taskkill /IM GHelper.exe /F
cd "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Python stuff"
python Battery_charge_limit_automation.py

if i run the code manually by running the bat file as administrator, it works perfectly fine
How can i fix this and make the task scheduler actually run the bat file when the scheduled time comes
here is the xml script
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2024-10-18T09:31:08.1047326</Date>
        <Author>LAPTOP-ADAM\User</Author>
        <URI>\AA modify Ghelper</URI>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Principals>
        <Principal id="Author">
            <UserId>S-1-5-21-1808867718-3794751144-1390657615-1001</UserId>
            <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
            <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
        </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
        <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
        <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
        <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
        <IdleSettings>
            <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
            <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
        </IdleSettings>
        <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    </Settings>
    <Triggers>
        <CalendarTrigger>
            <StartBoundary>2024-10-17T10:00:00</StartBoundary>
            <ScheduleByDay>
                <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
            </ScheduleByDay>
        </CalendarTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Actions Context="Author">
        <Exec>
            <Command>C:\Users\User\Documents\GHelper\run_automation.bat</Command>
            <WorkingDirectory>C:\Users\User\Documents\GHelper\</WorkingDirectory>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>



        


To get assistance with a scheduled task we need to see its configuration information. You can do that with the schtasks utility, e.g. %SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Query [/S system [/U username [/P password]]] /XML /TN taskname. You can [Edit] your question to provide us with that output, (within a code box).

alright, ive done that

Assuming that the code you submitted is run_automation.bat, what I am not understanding is why you have defined the task working directory as C:\Users\User\Documents\GHelper, and then proceeded to change that directory to C:\Users\User\Downloads\Python stuff in the batch file.
